# Overwriting values in listing page in EasyAdmin

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I have an associatation field, whats value can be null.

On the list page, I'd like to overwrite the `null` badge to my bagde, write `N/A` instead of `null`.

I tried with this:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    $fields = parent::configureFields($pageName);
    $learningPathField = AssociationField::new('LearningPath');
    if ($pageName === Action::INDEX) {
        $learningPathField->setTemplatePath('admin/EasyAdmin/na.html.twig');
        //$learningPathField->setTemplatePath('@EasyAdmin/crud/field/association.html.twig');
    }
    if ($pageName === Action::NEW) {
        $learningPathField->setHelp('Warning! Once you set this, you can not change when you edit Learning Path!');
    }
    if ($pageName === Action::EDIT) {
        $learningPathField->setDisabled(true);
    }
    $fields[] = $learningPathField;
    return $fields;
}
```

The problem is. it is always use my `na.html.twig` becuase at this point, I do not know anything about the value of the associated field.

So my question is, how can I change the template based on value of the associated field, but only for this index page?

Now I just created my on file like this:

```
{# @var ea \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Context\AdminContext #}
{# @var field \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\FieldDto #}
{# @var entity \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\EntityDto #}
{%  if (entity.instance.LearningPath) is null %}
    <span class="badge badge-outline">N/A</span>
{% else %}
    <a href="{{ field.customOptions.get('relatedUrl') }}">{{ field.formattedValue }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Is this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you just want to display in the listing of your entity a badge 'N/A' if the value of your Association field is null, and the link to this entity if it is not null.
You can simply define your field like this:

```php
final public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        // Other Fields
        AssociationField::new('category')
            ->setColumns(12),
    ];
}
```

[AssociationField](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields/AssociationField.html) will take care of the rest regarding your display in the list. For my part, by defining my field as indicated above, I have this result:
[image]

In French, 'Aucune' is for null values, and my link 'test' is for my defined category.

---

If you want to assign different badge based on the values of your field, you can use ChoiceField ([Documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields/ChoiceField.html)) with renderAsBadge to customize each badge according to its value.

```
ChoiceField::new('status')->renderAsBadges([
                Project::STATUS_PUBLISH => 'success',
                Project::STATUS_PENDING => 'primary',
                Project::STATUS_DELETED => 'danger',
            ])->setChoices([
                'Publié' => Project::STATUS_PUBLISH,
                'Brouillon' => Project::STATUS_PENDING,
                'Archivé - Non affiché' => Project::STATUS_DELETED,
```